# “Baking” incorrectly gives the size of the texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I am building a house. He pulled on all the walls and the floor textures, and the fact is that for each wall and floor I made an individual texture size (they themselves are of different sizes) so that they are all the same. For example: I attached the texture of bricks to the wall, and they look too huge in relation to other walls. I decided to expand the area between the "peaks" in the UV mapping, and the bricks decreased. So, now when I select the whole scene, I make an automatic scan in UV and I go to bake it all - after baking, these textures look just as unnaturally large and the dimensions I asked did not survive. How to fix?

Comment: Could you post some images to show what your problem is ? It is a bit hard to figure out what could be wrong with only a description

Comment: Oh, i already fix it. Just needed to expand the textures in the material.